# Key-Value Observing (KVO) vs. Bind(_:to:withKeyPath:options:)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm confused about the difference between the Key-Value Observing method `addObserver(_:forKeyPath:options:context:)` and its accompanying `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` *versus* the `bind(_:to:withKeyPath:options:)` method.

I know that according to Apple's [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002373-CJBEJBHH) the `bind` method seems to use the concepts from KVO and that:

> Cocoa bindings also use two protocols—`NSEditor` and `NSEditorRegistration`—that help to ensure that any pending edits are either discarded or committed before user interface elements are disposed of.

But, I also noticed KVO (and its sister, KVC) is a [Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notifications/nskeyvalueobserving) design pattern from `Foundation` while `bind` belongs to `Foundation`'s [Object Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/object_runtime) and `AppKit`'s [Data Management](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/data_management/nskeyvaluebindingcreation) design pattern.

I seem to see `bind` used whenever you're dealing with a subclass from `NSController` and you want to communicate with a model layer like `CoreData`. But, then, Apple's [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) says,

> Key-value observing provides a mechanism that allows objects to be notified of changes to specific properties of other objects. **It is particularly useful for communication between model and controller layers in an application.**

I've also seen KVO used for inter-object communication (*isn't that what delegates are for?*) in a few online tutorials.

**Both `bind` and KVO seem to do the same exact thing.**

*What's the difference between the two?*

*Which one should I use and what for?*

Any insight would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bindings is built on KVO, which is built on KVC. KVO is more general-purpose than Bindings, but there's a reason for the similarities.

Comment: Binding (with the default options) guarantees that if a setter is called for a value of one object, the setters for other values in other bound objects are called. KVO is observing.  A setter gets called, and you get a notification.  KVO ends there.  Bindings mean that after that notification, a second setter call in a second (bound) object is called.

Comment: In an nutshell, KVO is unidirectional: an observer gets notified when a property changes. Bindings are bi-directional: a property is "bound" to a view or representation—changing the property alters the view, and changing the view updates the property.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between the two?

KVO is the supporting technology for Cocoa Bindings. It allows an object to observe another one's property (if they are KVC compliant).

Cocoa Bindings are a concept on top of KVO that allows to objects to synchronise state. Usually a view and a controller.

For example, if I have an NSSlider's "value" binding bound to an integer property named "foo" of my class, the slider will observe "foo" (using KVO) and update the UI whenever I change its value. And if a user changes the slider via the UI it will  update "foo" for me.

Note that bindings should be documented by objects that support it. The binding name doesn't even need to be a property name. For example, see [contentSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSArrayController.html) from NSArrayController's bindings.

> Which one should I use and what for?

If you want to observe property values use KVO.

If you're working with Cocoa Bindings compatible objects (NSTableView, NSSlider, NSButton, NSArrayController, etc) you should consider Cocoa Bindings the reduce the amount of glue code you would have to write to synchronise UI and Controller data.